# Short SQL statement check

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm just wondering if the SQL statement below drop table "Final_Results", if table doesn’t contains any rows (except headers).

```
if exists(select * from Final_Results) 
    begin
        drop table Final_Results
    end
```

Many Thanks
Regards, Milos

Comment: Did you try it with a basic test table? Did it work?

Comment: It would drop if the there are records in Final_Results.Use NOT EXISTS instead .

Comment: This seems wrong-headed. It's a test relating to the *contents* of a table that then controls the *existence* of a table. Usually, you'd expect both the test and the change to be at the same "level" (test contents, delete contents or test existence, drop)

Comment: "except headers" -- Aside from what Kapil commented, what do you mean by "headers"? SQL doesn't have header rows. Do you just mean the column names? If so, those aren't rows. Or do you perhaps have some custom classification? If so, as far as SQL is concerned, those are no more or less headers than any other row.

Answer (score 0):

Use NOT EXISTS

```
if not exists(select * from Final_Results) 
    begin
        drop table Final_Results
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case , it will drop Final_Results table if there is one or more rows in the table,so you should use `Not Exists` instead:

```
if Not Exists(SELECT * FROM Final_Results) 
    begin
        DROP TABLE Final_Results
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

use count instead

```
if ((SELECT count(*) FROM Final_Results)=0) 
    begin
        DROP TABLE Final_Results
    end
```

Comment: Using `COUNT` rather than `EXISTS` is an anti-pattern, if all you need to know about is existence. If the optimizer is smart, the best it can do is the same as `EXISTS`. If the optimizer is dumb, it might actually *count all of the rows* instead of returning as soon as one row has been found.

Comment: it might be a solution.